# Twilio - Firefox MediaStreamError when trying to share screen in programmable video

Tags: firefox, twilio, react-redux, twilio-api

I am trying to share my screen using programmable video using Twilio on Firefox. However, I receive `MediaStreamError { name: "NotAllowedError", message: "The request is not allowed by the u…", constraint: "", stack: "" }`. Ideally I should see a pop-up asking the user to allow or deny permission.

```
Twilio.Video.connect(twilioToken, {
name: roomName,
audio: true,
video: {
  mediaSource: 'window' || 'screen' }
}).then....
```

Comment: What version of Firefox are you testing with? Does it work if you try the [screensharing on this test page](https://mozilla.github.io/webrtc-landing/gum_test.html)?

Comment: I am using 54.0.1. Yes, there is a pop-up asking if I want to share my screen.

Comment: Ok, one other thing, what is the rest of the message from the `MediaStreamError`? "The request is not allowed by the u..."

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I see.

Comment: Ok, I'd like to know the full error, so what you need to do is. In the Firefox dev tools console, where you see the error, right click on the error and choose "Store as global variable". This will store the error to the variable `temp0`. Then you can use `temp0` to query the object. So let me know the output of `temp0.message`. Thanks

Comment: temp0.message
    "The request is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the 
    current context."
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you already rejected access to screen sharing? That is the same error message I see if I reject access on the test page I sent earlier. Also, is this local or running on HTTPS?

Comment: So it turns out that the main culprit was the localhost. Apparently, screen sharing only works on HTTPS on Firefox. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The main culprit was the localhost. Apparently, screen sharing only works on HTTPS on Firefox. I tried to add localhost to the whitelist but that did not help.